# Getting JSON Exception no value for?

Tags: json, android-json

I am trying to handle the json response, that is like

```
{"Status":true,"UserId":111,"FirstName":"dev","LastName":"dev","Gender":-1,"BirthdayDate":"0000-00-00","Phone":"","ProfilePicture":"","ProfilePicture60px":"","ProfilePicture120px":"","CountryId":-1,"Email":"droidwithmxxmail.com","Password":"******123","RegisterDate":"2015-05-08 20:08:07","SessionId":"fce248fe6499b7a9338a1b64554509eb77841"}
```

but getting `org.json.JSONException: no value for exception`

My code is this.

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            allres =jsonObj.getJSONArray(jsonStr);

                for (int i = 0; i < allres.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = allres.getJSONObject(i);
                   userId = c.getString("UserId");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is all code for parsing?

Comment: of course not. i just posted the response code only

Comment: According to your code, you are first looking for an array, then for the individual object, but your example json doesn't have an array in it?

Comment: the response is like i posted above all. but do not how to handle this.

Comment: try remove jsonarray code and use it like jsonobject, or just remove JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr); and user allres = new JSONArray(jsonStr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
  try {

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
   userId = jsonObj.getString("UserId");

  } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your JSON string doesn't have an array in it, so the object that you will be getting from the first JSONObject is already where your information lives.

Comment: There is nothing for you to loop through, you can get each property by calling the jsonObj.getXX(). If the main object was contained in an array, then you could loop through the array to get each object's UserId, but not in this case

Comment: need your help in uploading images to server in given manner. please

Comment: You'll need to ask a question on SO and describe your problem there.

Comment: i will post the question but even i can't figuring out what the question sounds. like its very difficult for me to understand, i will send you the info than you give me the question i will post after that please answer me. its really very urgent.  please provide me your mail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132225/sending-multiple-data-to-server-in-predefined-format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164887/how-to-implode-files-in-java updated question please have a look.